# Increment value in Postgresql when adding new entry, using jpa/hibernate Spring

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 tables, one is manufacturer and one is monitor, in order to not apply the 1+n queries. I want to be able to increment the number of monitors under each manufacturer:

```
    manufacturer table:                      monitor
    id    name     totalMonitors             id     name     manufacturerId

    1     manuf1     100000                  1      mon1     1
    2     manuf2     2000                    2      mon2     2
```

Entity:

```
public class Manufacturer{

    private long id;

    private String name;

    private long totalMonitors;
}

public class Monitor{

    private long id;

    private String name;

    private Manufacturer manufacturer;
}
```

I use a DTO to work with the data. I am really puzzled by the way
         you can increment a value in the DB, for the query I will use a DAO interface.

```
     @QUERY("Query to get the number of total monitors for each manuf")
     long countByManufacturerId(List<Manufacturer> manufacturers);
```

As this will be a web application i canot count each time the number of monitors in the DB
         because this will lower the performance, what I want to know is if there is a solution
         to trigger an increment of the value "totalMonitors" whenever an operation of add/delete is
         is performed on the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Yuo could try looking at JPA Callback annotations.